# Java compute an array of booleans

Tags: java, arrays

at the moment I'm working on a registration form. I have a method which checks each field from an array to see if its empty or not and the result it's saved as a boolean in another array.

basically the user has to input his name, email and so on to register. I have a function which checks if all fields and empty or not and after that it stores the results in the boolean array.

How could I sum up the result of the boolean array?
How could I do something like this?

```
boolean resultOverAll = false;
boolean[] validationResultsPerField = new boolean[fields.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < validationResultsPerField.length; i++){
        if (validationResultsPerField[i] && validationResultsPerField[i+1]){
            resultOverAll = true;
        }
    }
```

Obviously my logic isn't the right one.

Comment: your Question is not clear . What do you exactly want ? where is your data from which you can calculate results ?

Comment: what is the meaning of resultOverAll ? if all records are valid then resultOverAll=true ? and if one of them is missing then resultOverAll= false ? am i correct ?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to check whether the boolean array is all true or not.

```
public static boolean areAllTrue(boolean[] array) {
    for(boolean b : array) if(!b) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: that's it! thank you mate, but could you please help me understand your code? It works just fine but I really don't understand this line     for(boolean b : array) if(!b) return false;

Comment: If any of the element is not true, then the overall result is false (so returning false without further iteration). If none of the element is false, then your array contains all true.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
boolean resultOverAll = true; // lets assume all fields are valid
for (int i = 0; i < validationResultsPerField.length; i++){
    if (!validationResultsPerField[i]){ // if you find any false then break
        resultOverAll = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check that all array elements are true. You can use functional programming using Java 8 Streams for this task:

```
Boolean[] validationResultsPerField = new Boolean[fields.length];
boolean resultOverAll = Stream.of(validationResultsPerField).allMatch(validationResult -> validationResult);
```